# Informar ou não "div" no CSS

Tags: css

Devo ou não informar o `div` no CSS?
Exemplo:

```
.teste {blablabla}
div.teste {blablabla}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="teste">teste</div>
```

Nunca informo, só que estava vendo o código de um site o qual ele foi informado.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Informar ou não** *div* como prefixo de uma classe, no css, depende do tipo do elemento que você quer que a regra seja aplicada, pois uma regra de css pode funcionar das seguintes maneiras:

```
div { blabla } //aplica a todas as div's do documento.
span { blabla } //aplica a todos os span do documento.
.teste { blabla } //aplica a todos os elementos que tiverem classe .teste
div.teste { blabla } //aplica APENAS AS DIVS que contem a classe .teste
span.teste { blabla } //aplica APENAS OS SPANS que contem a classe .teste
```

Por isso mesmo que a regra seja nomeada como a classe `.teste` apenas irá aplicar a todos os elementos que contem a classe `.teste` se não houver nenhuma especificação de tipo antes, como por exemplo `div.teste` aí seriam **todas as divs** que contem a classe `.teste` **e não todos os elementos**

Elementos são todos os tipos de elementos html existentes.

Divs são todas as tags `<div>` que existirem no seu html.

## Observação importante:

Não confunda `div .teste` com `div.teste` pois **são coisas bem diferentes** conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
div .teste { blabla } //aplica a todos os elementos que conterem classe .teste que forem filhos de uma DIV
div.teste { blabla } //aplica a todas as divs que conterem a classe .teste
```

Quando você dá um espaço no nome da regra, você está dizendo que o próximo elemento será filho do primeiro elemento (o da esquerda)

## Exemplos de Uso:

```css
div div {
  margin: 10px; /* apenas para dar um espaço */  
}

div, span {
  width:   150px; /* apenas para dar forma aos elementos */
  height:  50px;  /* apenas para dar forma aos elementos */
  margin:  10px;  /* apenas para dar um certo espaço */
  display: block; /* apenas para dar forma aos elementos */
  background-color: cyan;
}

.teste {
  background-color: blue;
}

div.teste {
  background-color: yellow;
}

span.teste {
  background-color: red;
}

div .teste {
  background-color: green;
}

.teste div {
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
}

.teste span {
  background-color: orange;  
}
```

```html
<div class=teste>div.teste</div>

<span class=teste>span.teste</span>

<div>
  <div class=teste>div .teste</div>
</div>

<div>
  <span class=teste>div .teste</span>
</div>

<div class=teste>
  <div>.teste div</div>
</div>

<div class=teste>
  <span>.teste span</span>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 pela observação sobre a diferença de `div .teste` e `div.teste`.

Comment: Explicação perfeita. Você poderia postar um exemplo do `div .teste { blabla }`? queria entender melhor como funcionam esses filhos.

Comment: eu coloquei os exemplos para você ver @FelipeStoker

Comment: Muito obrigado, explicação perfeita! Entendi agora.

Comment: Só quero acrescentar que, a não ser que seja estritamente necessário, não se deve especificar uma tag e uma class ou id na mesma regra de CSS pois isso causa o processamento da regra ser mais lento. Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS

Comment: Mas isso vai mais é de como está disposto o `html`, pois como podes ver, muita herança também deixa ele lento, por isto o `html` deve estar bem classificado e identificado para que isto funcione. Fora que propriedades que devem ser aplicadas a um conjunto inteiro de elementos é estritamente necessário o uso de tag, sem falar que esta diferença de performance deve ser insignificante ao usuário, na maioria dos casos.